# three dimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to print values in 3d array efter nested for loop in numpy.

```
import numpy as np 
center = 5
dim = 2
Bgr = 4

x = np.ones(dim)
y = np.zeros(dim)
z = np.ones(dim)
A =np.array(np.ones((dim,dim,dim)))*Bgr
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        for k in z: 
            print(A([[i],[j],[k]]))
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Replace `print(A([[i],[j],[k]]))` with `print(A[i,j,k])` Note that you should use `for i in range(dim)`, and the same for `j` and `k`.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem, I tried as suggested . still same error. TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: And why not just `print(A)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `len(np_array)` or `np_array.shape[0]` to get the no. of rows and then iterate

```py
for i in range (len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)): 
            print(A[i][j][k])
```